# Not able to compile an abstract class having an interface implemented

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

This is first of my question .I have got two classes and an interface .i am not able to compile the following code.Can anyone please help we out why the code is not compiling and running.

```
public interface Animals {
    public void run();

    public void eat();

    public void excreate();

    public void mate();
}

public abstract class Mammals implements Animals {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Run with Four Legs");
    }

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Eat Grass");
    }

    public void excreate() {
        System.out.println("Excreate Excreata");

    }

    public void mate() {
        System.out.println("Mammals Mate with a Mammal");
    }

    public abstract void giveBirth();


}

public class Horse extends Mammals {
    public void mate() {
        System.out.println("Horse Mates With A Mare");
    }

    public void giveBirth() {
        System.out.println("Giving Birth To Foal");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Horse h1 = new Horse();
        h1.eat();
        h1.run();
        h1.mate();
        h1.giveBirth();

    }
}
```

The Animal code Compiles successfully while the mammals and Horse class is not compiling .
The error is attached in the screen shot below
[scrren1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M48fQ.png)

Comment: Try to keep your classes in distinct files.

Comment: @Berger They are in separate Java files. Look at the screenshot: op compiles `Animals.java`, but fails on `Mammals.java`.

Comment: i already kept the source and class files in different folder but it is not compiling showing me the same error.Have been using eclipse but i dnt know the actual reason why it is not compiling from the cmdprompt

Comment: The problem was the classpath got it corrected and the lines of code is working fine now.Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're compiling files one by one, and javac can't find `Animals` when compiling `Mammals`. From the [javac docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#searching),

> When compiling a source file, the compiler often needs information about a type whose definition did not appear in the source files given on the command line.
>
> When the compiler needs type information, it looks for a source file or class file which defines the type. The compiler searches for class files first in the bootstrap and extension classes, then in the user class path (which by default is the current directory). The user class path is defined by setting the CLASSPATH environment variable or by using the -classpath command line option. (For details, see [Setting the Class Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)).
>
> If you set the -sourcepath option, the compiler searches the indicated path for source files; otherwise the compiler searches the user class path for both class files and source files.

As you can see from your screenshot, the directory you're compiling in isn't being searched for source *or* class files. `javac` is effectively unaware of what `Animals` is.

You can either set the source path/class path to contain your source folder or directly compile multiple source files, [as the javac docs show](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#examples):

> **Compiling Multiple Source Files**
>
> This example compiles all the source files in the package greetings.
>
> ```
> C:\>dir /B
> greetings
> C:\>dir greetings /B
> Aloha.java
> GutenTag.java
> Hello.java
> Hi.java
> C:\>javac greetings\*.java
> C:\>dir greetings /B
> Aloha.class                        
> Aloha.java                           
> GutenTag.class
> GutenTag.java
> Hello.class
> Hello.java
> Hi.class
> Hi.java
> ```

Comment: Better yet, use an IDE.

Comment: But as the default classpath is "." (current directory) the mere call (even one-by-one) should have found the compiled classes from previous compiles. @user2033516: Maybe you have some CLASSPATH value with your environment?

Comment: @Andreas Agreed. Unfortunately OP's screenshot is suggestive of a compsci course, and in my experience writing code in Notepad and compiling via command-line is taught as standard practice.

Comment: @rpy Doesn't matter if the default classpath is `.` (current directory), when the classpath has been set to `...\servlet-api.jar`. Look at the screenshot, where the "path for source files" and "path for class files" are both listed. It would appear that the `CLASS_PATH` environment variable is set, and it does not include the current directory.

Comment: Adding a .;with in the CLASSPATH variable solved the problem the code is compiling and working fine !!!! Have worked on eclipse before for a lot of applications but it was my choice to go with notepad++ this time here you don't get a trace of error you know.

Comment: @Kaushal I'm glad you got it working. If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark next to it. That will give us both some reputation and will mark your question as answered.